# Show child-items of any ONE top menu-item and hide/slideup child-items of other

Tags: jquery

I have small issue with a menu toggle. Below is a visual reference of the issue. Currently you can see that the child-items of BOTH the top links are visible. I need the child-items visible for only ONE top link at any given time. If one top link is clicked than other should hide / slideup its child-items.

---

[image]

---

**JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){ 
     var position = jQuery(this).position(); 
     jQuery('.sub-menu', this).slideDown('slow'); 
     }); 
});
```

**HTML** -  sample structure of the menu.

```
<ul class="menu">
<li class="menu-item" id="544" ><a href="#">Top Link One</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link one</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link two</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link three</a></li>
</ul>
</li>


<li class="menu-item" id="545"><a href="#">Top Link Two</a>
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link four</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link five</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">link six</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

I tried following a lot of similar issues here at SO but seems to be very specific to their own cases. I am just learning JS so please help me out here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the click handler to:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){ 
 jQuery('.menu-item .sub-menu').slideUp('slow'); //slideup all submenus first
 var position = jQuery(this).position(); 
 jQuery('.sub-menu', this).slideDown('slow'); 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: I intend to mark this as an accepted answer, because your answer came first and is accurate. All the other solutions work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `.not()` function effectively here to solve your problem,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){ 
       jQuery('.sub-menu').not(jQuery('.sub-menu', this).slideDown('slow')).slideUp('slow'); 
     }); 
});
```

Comment: very creative and done in few lines of code. Amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You can first hide all `sub-menu` and then make `sub-menu` visible which is under clicked `menu-item`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('.menu-item').click(function(){ 
 // hide all submenu first
 jQuery('.menu-item').find('.sub-menu').slideUp('slow');
 var position = jQuery(this).position(); 
 // show clicked submenu
 jQuery('.sub-menu', this).slideDown('slow'); 
 }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for being so descriptive, with comments and all. Gives me a chance to learn more.